# winston 'handleExceptions: true' logs twice

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

There is only one transport, added like this:

```
winston.add(winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({
            handleExceptions: true,
            format: winston.format.combine(
                winston.format.simple()
            ),
        }),
    ]
}));
```

When a new Error thrown from `index.js`:
`throw new Error('++++ I will log twice ++++')`
 will result in two separate logs!

I've also tried `transport.File({ ... })`, but the same result.

Update:
As [@terry-lennox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7237224/terry-lennox) mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55236098/winston-handleexceptions-true-logs-twice#55236827), the output is something like:

```
error: uncaughtException: ++++ I will log twice ++++
Error: ++++ I will log twice ++++
    at Object.
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
error: uncaughtException: ++++ I will log twice ++++
Error: ++++ I will log twice ++++
    at Object.
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
```

system setup versions:

```
OS: Windows 10 v1803
NodeJS: 10.14.1
express: 4.16.4
winston: 3.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of behaviour you're seeing:

```
error: uncaughtException: ++++ I will log twice ++++
Error: ++++ I will log twice ++++
    at Object.
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
```

Or do you see this repeated?

Comment: Yes it's a weird one. I'm having difficulty reproducing this.. I wonder if you could give me your OS & Node.js version?  I'm surprised at how different things like file I/O behave on different platforms.

Comment: Indeed, I've updated question to cover setup versions

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty normal for Javascript/node exception logging in my experience. It's not actually two logs, it's one log with newlines embedded.

If you break it down, it's basically:

```
[LOGLEVEL]: [MESSAGE]
[FULL EXCEPTION DUMP]
```

where I assume "MESSAGE" is winston printing "uncaughtException" + e.message.

And when you log an exception you get:

```
[EXCEPTIONAME]: [MESSAGE]
[STACK TRACE]
```

You can confirm this by switching to winston.format.json() - in that case it converts the whole log to JSON so you can see it's just one log.  And you can also confirm with simple log format by adding winstson.format.timestamp() - you'll see it only puts the timestamp at the beginning of that whole body of text, not on each line.